# Derivative question requring one to draw a graph!

Tags: derivatives

Is it possible to draw a function such that $f$ satifies:

1. $f(0)=1$
2. $f'(x)<0$ for all real $x \neq0$
3. $f''(0)=0$
4. $f'(0)=$ undefined
5. $f''(x)>0$ for all real $x > 0$
6. $f''(x)<0$ for all real $x < 0$

Comment: I was thinking of using a jump or point discontinuity at f(0), but I think that makes the second derivative at 0 also non-differentiable.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If $f\left(x_0\right)$ is undefined, certainly $f'\left(x_0\right)$ is undefined, just based on the definition of a derivative. This generalises to higher order derivatives as well.